# Count Least Possible Steps to Create zig-zag array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an array, I need to find the least possible changes you can make to the array to create a zig-zag pattern.

Edit: What you can change: any individual integer in the array can be changed to any other negative or positive integer. Each change counts as one change.

I am trying to do this:

1. count the number of steps it would take to make an array follow a Higher-Lower-Higher-Lower... pattern
2. count the number of steps it would take to make an array follow a Lower-Higher.... pattern
3. return whichever value is lower

This is what I have:

```
def minOperations(arr):
    def first(arr): 
        count1 = 0
        i = 1
        k = len(arr)
        while i < k-1:
            if arr[i-1] < arr[i] > arr[i+1] :
                i += 2
            elif arr[i-1] > arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
                arr[i] = arr[i-1]+1
                i += 2
                count1 += 1
            elif arr[i-1] < arr[i] < arr[i+1]:
                arr[i] = arr[i+1]+1
                i+= 2
                count1 += 1
            elif arr[i-1] == arr[i]:
                arr[i] = (abs(arr[i-1])+abs(arr[i+1]))
                count1 += 1
                i += 2
            elif arr[i-1] < arr[i] == arr[i+1]:
                arr[i] = arr[i+1]+1
                count1 += 1
                i += 2
            else:
                i += 1
        return count1
    
    def second(arr):
        ij = 1
        k = len(arr)
        count2=0
        while ij < k-1:
            if arr[ij-1] > arr[ij] < arr[ij+1] :
                ij += 2
            elif arr[ij-1] > arr[ij] > arr[ij+1]:
                arr[ij] = arr[ij+1]-1
                ij += 2
                count2 += 1
            elif arr[ij-1] < arr[ij] < arr[ij+1]:
                arr[ij] = arr[ij-1]-1
                ij+= 2
                count2 += 1
            elif arr[ij-1] == arr[ij]:
                arr[ij] = -arr[ij-1]
                count2 += 1
                ij += 2
            elif arr[ij] == arr[ij+1]:
                arr[ij] = arr[ij+1]-1 - abs(arr[ij-1])
                count2 += 1
                ij += 2
            else:
                ij += 1
        return count2
        
    count1 = first(arr)
    count2 = second(arr)
    return count1 if count1<count2 else count2
```

Edit 2: The input is any integer array; the output is an integer that indicates the least possible number of changes to create a zigzag pattern either starting with arr[0]>arr[1]<arr[2]>arr[3]... or arr[0]<arr[1]>arr[2]...

If I remove

```
def second(arr)...
```

It works well for the most part.

With this 1000 line input, I am struggling to get the correct output (below)

```
328197
363438
472137
345559
60946
627327
183828
849130
242550
892962
7187
281898
209661
790519
550382
624706
254124
782425
211198
659851
10354
357163
217450
883220
44827
955766
169162
854588
117042
903769
17762
885946
135683
445904
497484
958949
404979
186542
10898
641823
344338
880793
526586
911492
700304
938989
226824
165157
803100
993861
166742
928772
157133
867061
292956
90243
149877
470695
72677
977232
648027
569858
22317
892887
14025
171706
260033
828342
559788
876944
87869
794434
275226
915727
50276
823785
989018
425056
73215
642967
473985
771130
753696
233807
351268
746285
451650
681027
61847
803064
142924
890204
168920
947287
295166
291483
23263
681024
776371
997878
102663
321166
134949
829965
648311
878591
529136
745078
177903
78275
832972
959703
532512
463897
201307
425243
21888
975033
292061
194727
407446
909738
124842
777764
162651
662567
231691
717646
55756
971066
252498
238159
739710
978460
183002
977365
207875
648246
710076
948142
215751
242685
258102
864638
177147
229747
939399
932241
22872
794227
217924
232337
129451
222378
597788
914905
230122
854759
134067
504350
27561
904514
36274
762897
393025
264655
131081
987606
888853
754043
977050
732715
757720
741456
728966
920744
798
543591
249110
806599
308879
994725
573471
967319
439221
604181
58477
902805
510995
506352
362362
959919
565211
476263
27576
885937
400157
101338
262661
895580
229121
777818
964503
984581
491699
713034
193745
905040
31361
983969
317200
295865
160783
987288
159884
186978
41694
958739
994182
922872
424719
977047
109190
973826
479498
817424
354980
198544
61500
517363
23037
620589
230926
66926
207576
177396
302743
845741
825537
938814
583557
878375
238637
603651
12115
832149
847472
839401
804
661265
290065
621816
71446
737597
4181
982173
75138
486600
555688
681095
728118
888748
46659
810802
69
549599
104851
229697
381540
712053
347686
933548
247650
743351
84302
997960
62957
597689
488655
942522
484294
534092
203312
720374
483144
834370
305673
718235
364918
653087
229442
123224
134495
891738
670887
967626
89248
864129
151126
938639
138432
5214
66158
362661
222853
700786
45133
676405
803494
351289
21810
927950
15320
929592
5155
472950
169497
894672
120801
725758
619500
547694
28524
948142
225903
858028
28510
748989
167273
590548
67519
350189
55375
956223
702790
563110
292533
452575
67277
877019
754434
835717
20767
953471
173809
650835
151891
521316
205242
218007
56265
913137
66061
821257
60582
566025
179435
989696
347024
270780
144873
780658
92780
840431
291735
156864
349302
700372
130859
576462
412629
928774
556507
873185
411899
939763
262434
385892
108388
915159
106566
860734
396517
799058
18058
506397
623146
830562
67608
984449
94775
989789
884538
591099
71226
856843
100282
775910
11967
643223
153892
815066
42720
854598
15212
54041
36957
848847
732856
819383
135390
737982
57296
893295
560676
809539
791488
586312
84313
582595
91980
775586
48873
826671
827479
998851
904428
995151
143635
972117
950058
964104
131270
890428
290350
966854
97623
917920
157453
10120
361511
932771
15813
907585
339007
762581
102583
972461
840323
692793
729636
807253
856766
550142
289765
622888
619975
424141
977415
966652
30657
541677
415821
960728
47272
739919
300762
913847
61501
848489
80525
883427
247481
979434
50146
958739
247920
507894
484169
289573
982594
794655
100492
836137
151021
994348
122966
967989
182287
828264
48141
230447
143962
960671
573434
790754
38658
496945
12953
787685
256242
926000
172657
933034
487354
798104
453801
823459
11234
991942
116727
576391
461814
123890
325432
610035
480382
828031
4469
290066
131284
973092
60532
210258
358830
865727
57944
986482
16823
770264
74481
197650
10793
642297
16962
902237
777079
681962
700512
783454
176443
924479
349557
877241
207654
902509
73449
612458
29129
755547
18077
918403
128568
641007
182711
965469
47265
41143
61465
79311
135612
951546
22735
868128
704358
811349
39387
539892
946874
743027
154142
990373
332072
880675
938760
407495
341690
974812
278478
735654
234691
986436
140316
416537
36407
965504
304827
937473
260734
977852
152933
907524
187616
888363
436522
987305
656519
772481
328055
653446
227311
378351
394638
30687
25283
934339
3117
872381
166140
812168
688435
964276
347667
705230
115808
940031
294903
980610
55076
375923
80573
311950
468136
758353
191212
839169
245686
915738
131293
903068
141074
955285
388188
954095
129075
128928
263373
797046
266491
995049
628273
960800
66567
69127
61098
878089
123
699668
984976
895127
220031
939581
29749
994388
1320
949982
28634
849004
10266
613541
196380
984660
98345
997074
207798
952922
189705
164858
374786
876171
790207
968442
266027
243544
217943
690640
946609
776698
881703
70221
222314
964105
59961
978357
48529
878338
15179
990407
92183
932184
787799
901454
270989
728431
23765
222811
616164
219023
19955
769092
808504
550899
722723
912808
172846
771989
738710
818958
650669
176457
229587
292988
181425
103561
337825
761696
88039
917717
60143
664772
99961
985142
286124
784990
11843
54164
218203
899471
297103
767562
315044
858645
205953
644189
130421
739974
5219
586177
5583
857333
878900
913682
12960
652965
613322
997252
251004
220104
380202
845684
334917
951368
209577
823907
102519
21845
173914
742672
222100
507651
23063
985880
83772
566232
61129
170670
39797
891075
3583
964360
5224
927321
669554
992526
273589
78312
671954
915466
121923
850013
3338
876476
5212
495578
130474
487426
271587
816651
58460
278416
227535
884303
228687
660093
397348
851898
93338
778385
310449
639258
877448
366024
26610
880237
21023
136089
249222
428539
491685
851212
80734
727120
59089
808965
24763
356163
399712
486300
787365
814778
43432
732872
323521
843631
31254
653174
339844
679982
184657
960323
807314
395412
856508
913017
224117
725355
146413
722724
25988
912918
146255
962750
97375
760831
329082
198664
62189
998309
64327
912759
334927
974018
972488
925986
114922
826841
148960
851782
724731
915705
655480
662665
541710
182442
329411
962333
288501
585919
406460
433782
317811
838200
402317
975313
216259
879319
115537
723288
952426
820203
227715
740605
379197
25358
949486
84443
359426
750785
806696
882475
377821
204627
32755
992234
9128
944969
833
585486
964576
631439
605105
748724
226322
819242
601299
823059
229323
946733
177192
112452
8607
850708
718531
213095
160315
568756
712654
865907
43581
867157
396980
892108
380873
987459
424395
732801
991481
884131
317686
681721
61692
807032
136571
944546
945521
930013
92924
9194
21941
915733
127849
136100
31967
987334
152865
939505
33733
795893
75096
994529
695478
859934
277490
969429
287283
928623
92334
975776
190895
955485
209296
633376
695442
807863
29025
595913
50719
926766
311643
53989
608741
994526
243690
930411
119019
130867
47691
726931
105419
915314
89595
403712
449363
674701
20005
461330
74355
972027
130303
235828
186451
63342
32933
263523
819628
896245
101501
647686
180592
726535
```

count1 comes to 112

The correct output is 106

I'm thinking I've got the def first(arr) down alright where the only changes are addition. When the changes leading to the most efficient output include subtraction(s) then I'm missing those.

I have a feeling there is a much simpler solution. I just am not seeing it. How would you approach this problem?

PS: Thank you for bearing with me on my first stackoverflow post. Doing my best to provide the details to sort this out.

Comment: You may think it is obvious from your code. But pls explain: what constitutes a change or step in this problem?

Comment: What is your original `arr` and what is the target zig-zag pattern? Maybe you want to add more details to the example code.

Comment: Please provide (meaningful) sample input and corresponding zigzag pattern with the method used to count "changes"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can set each item to a minimum or maximum value beyond the range of all other values, you only need to change items that are not greater (or lower) than the previous one.  After making a change, because you set it extremely low or extremely high, the next item is always going to be ok. So in the worst case scenario, you only change half of the items.

You can simulate this in a loop that adjusts the items in alternating lower/greater checks.

```
A      = [... your large list of numbers ...]
minA   = min(A)-1
maxA   = max(A)+1
result = len(A)
for greaterThan in (True,False):
    prev  = A[0]
    count = 0
    for n in A[1:]:
        if (prev>n) != greaterThan:
            count += 1
            n = minA if greaterThan else maxA
        prev = n
        greaterThan = not greaterThan
    result = min(result,count)

print(result) # 106
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the task. A zigzag array is not a sorted array, and a change is not a swap. And for your sample data, the result should probably be 3, as it only takes 3 changes: turn indeces 1, 3, 5 all into `0` and you have a zigzag array.